# Displaying number with commas while typing in swiftUI textfield

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, formatter

I have one universal swiftUI application. In that application in textfield i want to allow only digits and . , also it should format text with comma(,) while user types. Only allow digits i have achieved using following code

```
TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                   // .padding(.leading, isPrefix ? 0 : -10) // Text Field padding
                    .padding(.horizontal, 12) // Text Field padding
                   // .padding(.horizontal, 12) // Text Field padding
                    .font(.arialDisplay(.regular, size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(isDarkMode ? .white : .black) // Set text color based on color scheme

                    .onChange(of: text, perform: { _ in
                        if text.count > 0 {
                          //  self.isPrefix = true

                        } else {
                           // self.isPrefix = false
                        }

                        // Callback for editing changes event
                        // Implement your editing changes logic here
                    })
                    .onSubmit {
                    }

                    .onReceive(Just(text)) { newValue in
                        let allowedCharacters = "0123456789.$,"
                        let filtered = newValue.filter { allowedCharacters.contains($0) }
                        if filtered != newValue {
                            self.text = filtered
                        }
                    }
```

comma formatting i have achieved using following code:
@State private var value = 0.0
//...

TextField("Value",
value: $value,
format: .number
.grouping(.automatic)
.precision(.fractionLength(2)
)

When i apply formatter it breaks my number only logic. As app is for ipad also, i can't rely on setting keyboard type.How to format text with , as user types and allow only numbers and dots ?.For an ex. 250000 should be displayed as 250,000. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the combined solution for formatting number and allowing number, dot,comma and dollar only. When i combine solution then only formatting works, number only solutions does not work

import SwiftUI
import Combine
extension String {
func toDouble() -> Double? {
return NumberFormatter().number(from: self)?.doubleValue
}
}

struct Solution2: View {

```
@State private var text: Double = 0

var body: some View {
    TextField("",value: $text, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
        .onChange(of: text, perform: { newValue in 
            
        })
    
        .onReceive(Just(text)) { newValue in
            
            let newString: String = String(format: "%f", newValue)

            let allowedCharacters = "0123456789.$,"
            let filtered = newString.filter { allowedCharacters.contains($0) }
            if filtered != newString {
                self.text = filtered.toDouble() ?? 0
            }
        }

    
          }
```

}

Comment: You are contradicting yourself, you want to format a value using comma as a thousand separator but you are not allowing commas in the text field.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel use the tools available to you, `TextField` has a constructor that takes a numeric property and a format that will format the content automatically for you.

Even if it doesn't match your requirements to 100% I still believe it's better to use this instead of writing a lot of custom code.

Here is an example that format the entered number with a thousand separator and 2 decimal digits in the users locale

Edit - fixed an issue with the syntax of the TextField.

```
@State private var value = 0.0
//...

TextField("Value",     
          value: $value,
          format: .number
          .grouping(.automatic)
          .precision(.fractionLength(2)
    ))
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. A NumberFormatter() is just not working smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

`let formatter: NumberFormatter = {let formatter = NumberFormatter() formatter.numberStyle = .decimal return formatter }()`

Please add above formatter

and use this formatter by

`TextField("placeholder", value: $text, formatter: formatted)`

Comment: When i use above formatter my filter with just operator for numbers does not work. App is in ipad also, so changing keyboard type will not work